# Catalina zsh shell change breaks jupyter notebook PATH

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, zsh, macos-catalina

Since my upgrade to macOS Catalina, I switched my default shell to zsh (per recommendation by Apple).  However, now I can't run `jupyter notebook` on the shell anymore.  I get the following error:

`zsh: command not found: jupyter`

I saw several responses suggesting to modify the PATH by appending a line to the end of the `~/.zshrc` file.  What directory should I add to the end of the `~/.zshrc` file?  Is that even the right file to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
which pip3
```

you should get something like (in Mac):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
```

Now run:

```
export PATH=/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

Now try to run jupyter, if it works for you, just add it to your `.zshrc`

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're suggesting that I add the `which pip3` directory to the PATH instead of actually `/Library/Python/3.6/bin`, correct?

Comment: Adding the path that `which python3` points to worked!  Thank you!